# How can I determine whether a string is an email, id, or username in PHP?

Tags: php

I am writing a member search form for my admin panel in PHP.  There is a single field for search criteria and I want the script to determine if it should search the database for an email address, a username, or an ID.  My current script always returns that the column is "display_name", even when I enter an ID or email.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$criteria = "billgates@microsoft.com";
if(!preg_match("^([0-9]+)^", $criteria)){

            if(!preg_match("^([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)^", $criteria)){

                if(!preg_match("^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)^", $criteria)){

                    $this->error = "Your search criteria of '".$criteria."'' is not a valid display name, email address, or ID.";

                } else {

                    $column = "email_address";

                }

            } else {

                $column = "display_name";

            }

        } else {

            $column = "user_id";

        }

echo $column;
```

The above will produce "display_name".

Comment: Why not just do `select * from accounts where display_name=$criteria or email_address=$criteria or user_id=$criteria`?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can simply try this solution. its worked for me.

```
<?php
$criteria = "billgates@microsoft.com";
if(!is_numeric($criteria)){

        if(filter_var($criteria, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){            
            $column = "email_address";
        } else {
            $column = "display_name";
        }
    } else {
        $column = "user_id";
    }
echo $column;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regexes are using "^" as a delimiter. The de facto standard delimiter is "/". And "^" matches the beginning of the string. If you want to match the end then you need to use "$". Inside the delimiters, of course.

Comment: I am not sure if this is because I am on wamp or if it's the PHP version or what, but when I use $ at the end I get the error No ending delimiter '^' found

Answer (score 0):

You have few mistakes in your `preg_match` regular expression. check the code below.

```
$criteria = "2312";
if (!preg_match("/^[1-9][0-9]*$/", $criteria)) {

    if (!preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)$/", $criteria)) {

        if (!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,})$/", $criteria)) {

            $this->error = "Your search criteria of '" . $criteria . "'' is not a valid display name, email address, or ID.";
        } else {

            $column = "email_address";
        }
    } else {

        $column = "display_name";
    }
} else {

    $column = "user_id";
}

echo $column;
```

Check the working http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2z65-4rdv

Answer (score 0):

```
$criteria = "billgates@microsoft.com";
if(!filter_var($criteria, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
    $column = "email_address";
else if(is_numeric($criteria))
    $column = "display_name";
else
    $column = "user_id";
echo $column;
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post.

Answer (score -1):

So I came to my conclusion which uses a bit of everybody's responses.  Instead of using regex, i used PHP functions is_numeric, ctype_alnum, and the filter to validate the email while maintaining the same structure of my old code.  I did not want to eliminate the validation of the display name by saying that if the string was not an ID or an email, then it's a display name.  This is because the display names follow a certain format and any old string can be entered with that method.  Here's what I came up with...

```
if(!is_numeric($criteria)){

            if(!ctype_alnum($criteria)){

                if(!filter_var($criteria, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

                    $this->error = "Your search criteria of '".$criteria."'' is not a valid display name, email address, or ID.";

                } else {

                    $column = "email_address";

                }

            } else {

                $column = "display_name";

            }

        } else {

            $column = "user_id";

        }
```